# TreeMap Constructor using comparator error in Java

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

I want to make a TreeMap, so that each time an entry is inserted in the TreeMap - the entry is sorted based on value on the run. (needs O(logN) time.) So, I define a TreeMap with its constructor like below :: I dont understand where is the problem... i am confused. Can anyone please explain me the error/problem ?

Code ::

```
Map<String,Integer> tm = 
  new TreeMap<String,Integer>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // implement logic here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

The comparator is for the key

```
Map<String,Integer> tm =
                    new TreeMap<String,Integer>(new Comparator<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // implement logic here
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: So, if I want the Treeap to sorted on based on value OR based on combination of key-value .... then what change in the "new Comparator<String>()" I should have to make ??

Comment: @Ronin When we say map is sorted, we mean that the entries are sorted by keys. Map is a key-value collection; it's not something like list.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to search on the key-value; basically for this map under the hood you get a tree for the keys. if you want on a combination of key-value doesn't look to be a map but more a set(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html and you build a custom object with string and int). for this map you get log n when you search on the key;

Comment: Is it possible to get a TreeMap with a property that its sorts its entry based on value only, by changing "new Comparator<String>( )" or anyhow ?

Comment: sorry; maybe i didn't understood what you want to achieve; why do you need the key then?

Comment: Basically, I want to get a TreeMap with a property that whenever an entry is inserted it will be in a place so that the TreeMap is sorted based on its "value". How I can achieve that ? Apology if I was not clear.

Comment: but I can't think at any advantage by doing that. if you get the value from the treemap based on the key you get log(n) (as you asked) so the question still stands: why do you need that?

Comment: Because, I want to store the top ten "Value" in the TreeMap at a time. Even if the data grows more than 10, only the top 10, should reside in TreeMap. what would be best way to do it using comparator ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39254/discussion-between-user1121883-and-ronin)

Answer (score 0):

You should sort entries based on the entry's key. So comparator should compare two strings here. (new Comparator(){...}) as suggested in other answer here.

Take a look at constructor documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to sort by the value, you should create a new object for the key, also containing your value:

```
class MyKey {
    String str;
    Integer i;
    ...
}
Map<MyKey,Integer> tm = new TreeMap<MyKey, Integer>(new Comparator<MyKey>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyKey o1, MyKey o2) {
         String str1 = o1.str;
         String str2 = o2.str;
         // implement logic here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide comparator, which compares keys, rather then full map entries. So to create `TreeMap<String,X>` (`X` is any type) you need to provide `Comparator<String>`. This can be done like this:

```
Map<String,Integer> tm = new TreeMap<String,Integer>(new Comparator<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                            // implement logic here
                            // sample implementation below 
                            return o1.comparateTo(o2)
                        }
                    });
```

If natural ordering of strings (see: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) for String#compareTo) is fine for you, you can just write:

```
Map<String,Integer> tm = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
```

Notice that in both cases, ordering of keys is the same. In both cases `String#compareTo` method is used to compare keys. Only in the first example we are providing comparator explicitly and in the second one we using the fact that `String` implements `Comparable`.

Comment: this code doesn't work for me. do you think that it is deprecated?